# Multiple inputs with same name through POST in php is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form with 2 inputs as below. I am sending POST request through ajax

```
<input name="item_name[]" value="Monthly" id="i1"/>
<input name="item_name[]" value="Weekly"  id="i2" />

xmlhttp.open("POST","validation.php",true);
var params = "item_name="+document.getElementById('i1').value+"item_name="+document.getElementById('i2').value;
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

When i submit the page in php, i am not able to read both values. The array shows only one character of the first value.

```
echo '1.'.$_POST['item_name'][0].' 2.'.$_POST['item_name'][1];
```

**Output is** : `1.M 2.o`

**Expected output** is `1.Monthly 2.Weekly`

Even , i tried printing `$_POST['item_name']` , it shows **Monthly** only.

Chrome --> Developer Tools --> Gives proper output as well. I dont know where the problem is ?

[image]

Comment: Works fine, are you sure they are spelled the same and have the `[]` ?

Comment: @AbraCadaver : I have added more details to my question. I am submitting the page through AJAX request.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: (now with Ajax. I use JQuery here but the concept should stay similar)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myData = new Array();
    myData[0]="one";
    myData[1]="two";

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: 'test2.php',
        data: {'data':myData},
        success: function(output) {
            //do something
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

result in PHP (var_dump($_POST))

```
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "one"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "two"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added more details to my question. I am submitting the page through AJAX request

Comment: Edited it. However i always use JQuery as it's ways easier this in my opinion. Hope this still helps.

Comment: If you see a snapshot given in question, it sends two values properly but PHP is not able to recognize it.

Comment: If you var_dump $_POST and the values are not displayed correctly you have an error in your ajax-request/JS and not in PHP. So you might be searching at the wrong place.

Comment: var_dump $_POST only returns 1 record. the second one is not coming though the Chrome page tells it sent two of the values

Comment: see my working answer

Answer (score 1):

Found answer myself..
Need to add `[]` symbol in the javascript code. Its working fine now..

```
var params = "item_name[]="+document.getElementById('i1').value+"item_name[]="+document.getElementById('i2').value;
```